# visual studio - form not updating with sql database

Tags: c#, sql

I have an issue where I have created a form, added a table through a DataSource to an SQL database. Everything has worked fine.

I have now needed to change a column from varchar(8) to varchar(255) which has been done and is fine. My issue is that upon opening my form I have a red ! on my columns saying ;

> Column 'UserId' exceeds the MaxLength limit.

It lets me add through the form to the database with no issue. But always populates this issue on form opening.

Please may somebody point me in the right direction to get the form to update along with the SQL Database?

I assume it is the Adaptor but I very well may be wrong. I am new to VS and I have not been able to find the correct answer so far so I am hoping for some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are using a Typed Dataset. If so open the dataset in the designer go to the table in question click on the UserId column and change its MaxLength Property as needed.

Comment: are you attaching the DataSource at design time..? if so clear it and reassign it if you are using a DataAdapter and doing the `Binding` at design time then you need to clear it at design time.. try setting it at run time also if you are using `Typed DataSet` yuk... move away from that and start using sql objects to connect to the database to return the data for display

Comment: The column has defaulted to 32767 MaxInputLength so it is more than needed. And I have made a datasource connection. Then dragged my table over to a form and let VS add all it needs to so far. If that is any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate DataSource object - it has validation rule that still have old length restriction.

Comment: Does this mean to drop the DataSource and then re-add it basically?

Comment: Yes, this will help. Or alternatively you can manually find that validation rule and change it's value.